# Hide and re-appear floating action button, android

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm using floating action button in my android application. I've implemented a feature when a user scrolls down the list, FAB disappears. It appears back when a user scrolls up.

```
    myRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if (dy >0) {
                // Scroll Down
                if (floatingActionButton.isShown()) {
                    floatingActionButton.hide();
                }
            }
            else if (dy <0) {
                // Scroll Up
                if (!floatingActionButton.isShown()) {
                    floatingActionButton.show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

How to make FAB re-appear after 5 seconds even if the user doesn't scroll up?
If you're still not clear with my question, you can check this feature out in LinkedIn android application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use View.postDelayed() thread.
For ex:

```
floatingActionButton.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       floatingActionButton.show();
   }
},5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timertask class or could do it using runnable and handler